# click on bootstrap dropdown menu link doesn't trigger html request

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So, I have usual bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <button class="btn">25</button>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="/dashboard/alerts_paginate/5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dashboard/alerts_paginate/15">15</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dashboard/alerts_paginate/25">25</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dashboard/alerts_paginate/50">50</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I want it to trigger HTML request to my Rails app when clicking on a link. Right now it just hiding dropdown-menu when clicked. Am I doing something wrong or this is standart behaviour?